# How to limit YOLO to a fixed number of predictions?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Let's say I annotated **all images** in my dataset to have **20 Bounding Boxes**.

I basically want my predicted bounding boxes to also be only **20**. After training however, I get differing amounts of bounding boxes, that aren't 20.

I'm trying to detect the same 20 objects in an image. All the objects are the same so I only 1 class for all **20 bounding boxes**.

I'm currently using YOLOv5 but is there a better model for a use-case like this?

Comment: Do you mean that you would to improve the model accuracy or limit the detection in the image to only 20 detected objects ? (Your question is not very clear!)

Comment: I want to limit the detection in the image to only 20 detected objects. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I realize now that Yolo probably isn't built for this. I was hoping that if all images in my dataset are annotated to have "20 detected objects", the Yolo model would also output 20 of those detected objects. But right now, I'm getting more than that, there are also a multiple bounding boxes on a single object (which can probably be solved by a non-max suppression algorithm).

I was maybe hoping if there was a model that would output a fixed number detected objects (20 bounding boxes) per image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest selecting the 20 detected objects with higher confidence, you can do that easily by appending the all detected objects boxes to a list as well as the confidence and labels and then iterated through the list with range limitation, and then you can draw the bounding box of the filtered objects (20 objects).

Comment: Thanks! I actually decided on just: Increasing the confidence `model.conf = 0.5`, then [Sorting it with pandas and getting the head of the first 20](https://docs.ultralytics.com/tutorials/pytorch-hub/#sorted-results). Do you have any idea how to turn the sorted results in pandas `results.pandas()` back into just `results` so I can access util methods like `results.render()` or `results.crop()`? [Here's my other question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339150/how-to-convert-yolov5-model-result-to-pandas-then-back-to-model-result).