# How to convert YoloV5 Model Result to Pandas then back to Model Result

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

### tl; don't want to read

How do I convert YoloV5 model `results` into `results.pandas()`, [sort it](https://docs.ultralytics.com/tutorials/pytorch-hub/#sorted-results), then convert it back into `results` so I can access the useful methods like `results.render()` or `results.crop()`?

### Context:

I've recently learned how to load and do inference with a YoloV5 model:

```py
# Load model
model = torch.hub.load('./yolov5', 'custom', path='/content/drive/MyDrive/models/best.pt', source='local')  # local repo

# Import Image
im1 = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg'
im2 = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg'

# Do Inference
results = model([im1, im2])
```

I also learned that this `results` object returned from inference has really useful methods for getting the result in different formats:

```py
imgs = results.render() # gives image results with bounding boxes
crops = results.crop(save=True) # cropped detections dictionary
df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # Pandas DataFrame of 1 image
n_df = results.pandas().xyxyn[0]  # Pandas DataFrame of 1 image with normalized coordinates
```

My use-case here was to sort it, then get the top 20 in terms of confidence.

```py
top_20 = results.pandas().xyxy[0].sort_values('score',ascending = False).groupby('confidence').head(20) # get top 17 sorted by confidence
```

Now I'm not sure how to turn it back to just results, so I can also access the same utility methods like `.render()` and `.crop()`

---

I think I could also create my own `render` and `crop` functions with OpenCV using my sorted dataframes as args, but I was just wondering if there was a more intuitive way to just reuse those utility methods.